# Rendering matcap with ambient occlusion using blender internal render and cycles

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, matcaps

I'm using matcaps as materials most of time, using blender internal render and cycles with nodes or without, by making the material shadeless and setting the mapping coordinates to *normal*.
I want ambient occlusion to affect the final render.

[image: render without ambient occlusion]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enable the *Ambient Occlusion* in the *World* section of the *properties panel*. Set it to **Add**.
   [image]
2. Create a new material: "Ambient".
3. Set the Diffuse Intensity to 1, and the Color to (1, 1, 1). Rendered view will show the ambient occlusion of the material.
   [image]
4. Create a new material: "mixedMaterial". Assign it to the mesh.
5. Enable nodes, add the "Ambient" Material, the "Matcap" Material and combine them with a **Color Mix** node. Set the Mix nodes mode to **Multiply**.
   [image]

This is the result.

[image]

Comment: After apply your advice -- it works thanks :) but I need to control Ambient Occlusion on [Node] like here on 3D viewport

Comment: here ---->>> [link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65048/control-ambient-occlusion-on-node-like-here-on-3d-viewport)